# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using GitPython to fetch a remote repository to my machine. The following code works well on my Ubuntu 12.04 but on my amazon ec2, on a Ubuntu 11.10 server, I get the OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error.

```
    repo = git.Repo.init(fs_path)
    origin = repo.create_remote('origin',repo_url)
    origin.fetch()
    origin.pull(origin.refs[0].remote_head)
```

When I run the block in a script, I don't get any error messages. But when I try these steps on Interactive shell I get this stack trace:

```
>>> import git
>>> repo = git.Repo.init("/var/wwww/dir/subdir/tmp/12")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/repo/base.py", line 656, in init
    output = git.init(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 227, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 456, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 335, in execute
    **subprocess_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1239, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>>
```

But I have no such issues on my local machine. No idea what's going wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: the path exists and python can access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming out of the `subprocess` module.  This suggests that `git` is either not installed on your EC2 instance or is in a location that is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Note that `GitPython` depends on the `git` command-line tools.  If you want a native Python module for interacting with Git repositories, take a look at [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/).

Comment: I just found that out myself and came here to answer the question. Yes, indeed I didn't have git installed and that was causing the error. Thanks for your prompt reply. 

I just wish Gitpython emitted a more meaningful error message/exception. If a library depends on an external tool, the first thing the library should do is to check if the dependency is installed. Had a tough hour with this. 

Thanks again!