# GitPython: check if git is available

Tags: python, git, gitpython

GitPython depends on having the command line version of `git` installed (otherwise, you get the issue in this question: [OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804744/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-on-gitpython/10805177#10805177)).

Is there any way from the GitPython API to check if the executable is found, or, do you need to wrap all GitPython calls in exception handling to account for this possibility?

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly recommend this, but I actually *did* it at least once: try one git command while catching the OSError case to see if you can run git (and by running it, capture the git version number as well, in my case).  If git fails to run, complain and disable further invocations of git (or exit immediately or whatever).  If not, assume further invocations will continue to work.

Comment: is there some way to disable GitPython from going out to git.exe - or, you just mean that I should store a flag (in python ), indicating that git is not available?

Comment: I mean the latter (your own flag), yes.