# How to clone a private git repo in aws lambda

Tags: github, aws-lambda

I need to clone a private git repo within aws lambda (lambda runtime is python). After doing some research, I know that the I need to clone the repo in `/tmp` directory because it is the only accessible directory in lambda. In addition, I need to use a private key to ssh to github.

Basically, my code looks like:

```
import git # lambda-git
import os

private_key = """-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
"""
with open("/tmp/id_rsa", "w") as id_rsa:
  id_rsa.write(private_key)
os.chmod("/tmp/id_rsa", 600)
os.environ["GIT_SSH_COMMAND"] = 'ssh -i /tmp/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
git.exec_command("clone", "git@domain:repo_name.git", "/tmp")
```

However, after uploading the zipped folder into lambda, I got the following error

```
Could not create directory \\'/home/sbx_user1051/.ssh\\'.
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/sbx_user1051/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key \"/tmp/id_rsa\": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing? Or is it even possible to clone a private repo within aws lambda?
Any help is appreciated.

PS. I know that I can use a git token and clone the repo over https. But I cannot modify the repo url and have to use `git@domain:repo_name.git` as it is.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the answer.
Changing permission code from `600` to `0o600` solved this problem!

Comment: Can you share some more details on how you accomplished this? I'm looking at the exact same problem. One thing I did different was store my private key in Amazon Secret Manager instead of inside the function, then called the get_secret() function inside of the lambda_handler function. The permission thing worked (I had to change my permission bit to 0o0600 but other than that it worked perfectly), but now I'm getting that it can't save the known_hosts file in my /home/user directory... which I don't want anyways... basically I'm wondering did you ever get this to work?

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your solution @coding-monkey

My problem was that I used os.system("export GIT_SSH_COMMAND... instead of os.environ["GIT_SSH_COMMAND"]

Just in case someone needs, here is my solution:

```
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.system('rm -rf /tmp/*')
    os.system("""cat >/tmp/id_rsa <<EOL
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
ATTENTION, DO NOT STORE PRIVATE KEYS IN CODE, THIS IS ONLY DEMONSTRATION
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
EOL""")
    os.chmod('/tmp/id_rsa', 0o600)
    os.system('ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | tee /tmp/known_hosts | ssh-keygen -lf -')
    os.environ['GIT_SSH_COMMAND'] = 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts -i /tmp/id_rsa'
    os.system('git clone git@github.com:<privaterepo>.git /tmp/aws2')
    return {"test": "123"}
```

Comment: this is not working for me. I am still getting error. Could not create directory '/home/sbx_user1051/.ssh'. Permission denied (publickey).